# Compare two columns in CSV file for equality check

Tags: python

```
Column1 Column2
A         B
B         C
C         C
E         E
```

Here third and fourth rows are equal,C and C, E and E. The output should be C and E.

Comment: Well, have you tried iterating each row of the CSV and checking them?

Comment: I've tried to solve this using Numpy...
comparison = np.where(df["Coloumn1"] == df["Column2"], True, False)

This only show the matching columns as TRUE and unmatching as FALSE,
But i need to print them. (Both C and E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, import the file with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file')
```

Then, just compare them in the following manner and print:

```
matched_values = df['Column1'][df['Column1']==df['Column2']].values
print(matched_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

First ingest the data using `pandas`:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv')
```

I will use a toy `DataFrame` to illustrate:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b':[0,2,3,0]})
```

Then all you have to do is query appropriately, select one of the columns and get your result in a multitude of ways. I am using `.values` to get a `numpy` list:

```py
>>> df.query('`Column 1` == `Column 2`')['Column 1'].values
array([2, 3])
```

You could use `.tolist()` to get a plain `python` list instead.